# Handling different php responses after a javascript http post request

Tags: php, javascript, android, http-post

I am developing an android application that uses the PHP/MySQL to send data from app to server in order to register/login users. I already wrote the Javascript and PHP files to send and receive JSON data an insert it into MySQL database. The problem I have is how to handle different responses from PHP.

Exemple:

```
<?php

   //decode json object
   $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $obj = json_decode($json);

   //variables
   $user_firstname = $obj->{'user_firstname'};
   $user_lastname = $obj->{'user_lastname'};
   $user_email = $obj->{'user_email'};
   $user_password = $obj->{'user_password'};

   if([variables] != null){
      //check for an existing email in db
      mysql_query("Check if email exists");

      if(email exist){
         //pass a response to java file
         return user_exists;
         die();
      }else{
         //success
         return success;
      }
   }

?>
```

All I want is to handle those different return values in order to interact with the user inside the android app.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should user HTTP response codes for this. For example, your php script will return `HTTP 200 - OK`  when user successfully created and `HTTP 409 Conflict` when user already exists. This is how RESTfull APIs usually works this. On Android you'll have to check the status code and decide what to do.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com/");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can craft a json response by creating an associative array and passing it to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which will return a string that you can echo to the java client. Don't forget to set the [appropriate `Content-Type` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) using the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. It's also a good idea to set the HTTP response code appropriately. I'm picturing something like this:

```
$responseArray = array('response' => 'success'); // or 'user_exists'
$responseJson = json_encode($responseArray);
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); // or 4xx FAIL_TEXT on failure
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $responseJson;
```

You'll then have to parse this response on the java client.